# How can I mock the Azure Redis Cache?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks, justmock

How can I mock the Azure Redis Cache?

I would like to write unit test for one of my application which uses Azure Redis Cache. Since I am completely new to mocking and stubbing in writing unit test code, I am looking for help in how I can start with the basic script for mocking/stubbing cache component.

Answer (score 2):

Testing with external resources like databases, files, and caches is *integration* testing, non *unit*. What you can test in unit-tests is the fact, that your code is calling caching methods.

So, first, you need an interface of *cache service*. This interface not only let you test your code, but also let you use different caching servers.

```
public interface ICache
{
    void Add<T>(string key, TimeSpan lifetime, T value);

    bool TryGet<T>(string key, out T value);

    void Remove(string key);

    . . .
}
```

Second, you need domain code to test:

```
public class SleepingMembersService
{
    private readonly TimeStamp _lifetime = TimeStamp.FromMinutes(5);
    private readonly ICache _cache;
    private readonly INotifier _notifier;

    public SleepingMembersService(ICache cache, INotifier notifier)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _notifier = notifier;
    }

    private string MakeKey(User user) => $"unsleepingUser{user.Id}";

    public void WakeUpIfSleep(IUser user)
    {
        var key = MakeKey(user);
        bool isWaking;
        if (_cache.TryGet(key, out isWaking) && isWaking)
            return;

        notifier.Notify(user.Id, "Wake up!");            
    }

    public void ConfirmImNotSleeping(IUser user)
    {
        var key = MakeKey(user);
        _cache.Add(key, _lifeTime, true);
    }
}
```

Third, let's make stub cache:

```
public class StubCache : ICache
{
    public bool TryGetResult { get; set; }

    public bool TryGetValue { get; set; }

    public bool AddValue { get; set; }

    public TimeStamp LifeTimeValue { get; set; }

    void Add<T>(string key, TimeSpan lifetime, T value)
    {
        LifeTimeValue = lifetime;
        AddValue = (bool)(object)value;
    }

    bool TryGet<T>(string key, out T value)
    {
        value = (T)(object)TryGetValue;
        return TryGetResult;
    }

    . . .
}
```

And finally you can write unit-test:

```
pubic void ConfirmImNotSleeping_WhenCalled_CallsAdd()
{
    var cache = new StubCache<bool>();
    var notifier = new StubNotifier();
    var service = new SleepingMembersService(cache, notifier);
    var user = new StubUser(1, "John Doe");

    service.ConfirmNotSleeping(user);

    Assert.IsTrue(cache.AddValue);
}
```

Well, you've checked that the method `ConfirmNotSleeping` calls the method `Add`.

Now, you should implement `ICache` for Redis:

```
public RedisCache : ICache
{
    private IConnectionMultiplexer connection;

    public bool TryGet<T>(string key, out T value)
    {
        var cache = Connection.GetDatabase();

        var rValue = cache.StringGet(key);
        if (!rValue.HasValue)
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rValue);
        return true;
    }

    . . .    
}
```

To simplify implement stubs and mocks you can use libraries like [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4). These libraries let you automatically generate stubs and mocks for your purpose. So you test code will look like this:

```
pubic void ConfirmImNotSleeping_WhenCalled_CallsAdd()
{
    var cacheStub = new Mock<ICache>();
    var notifierStub = new Mock<INotifier>();
    var service = new SleepingMembersService(cache.Object, notifier.Object);
    var userStub = new Mock<IUser>();

    service.ConfirmNotSleeping(user.Object);

    cacheStub.Vertify(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<TimeStamp>(), true));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help!
But, the third step is giving compilation error in - 

void Add<T>(string key, TimeSpan lifetime, T value)
    {
        LifeTimeValue = lifetime;
        AddValue = value;
    }

Due to the type of value is T.

Comment: It would be great, if you could give a simple example of set and get an object from Redis cache and subsequently the testing code. Thanks!

Comment: I corrected the error in the implementation of methods `Add` and `TryGet`. With regard to your second comment: my answer describes the unit testion of cache logic. If you want to call Redis methods in tests, there will be integration tests, not unit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion/ reply.